# How to pass a selector's attribute as a function parameter

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this following elements

```
<div class="mydiv" data-custom="ABC"></div>
<div class="mydiv" data-custom="DEF"></div>
```

How can I call a jquery and pass as a parameter an attribute of the selector.  Would be something like this:

```
$(".mydiv").text( $(this).attr("data-custom") );
```

This doesn't work.  What is the right way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) can take a function as an argument, the value returned by the function will be assigned as the text context of the node

```
$(".mydiv").text( function(){
    return $(this).attr("data-custom")
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JzKNB/)